# AngularJS - variable name with a string

Tags: angularjs, scope

I have a bilingual app. I have a variable $scope.language = 'fr' or 'en'. I would like to add that to a variable.

```
{{ factsheet.name_$scope.language }}
```

So that the result would call `{{ factsheet.name_en }}`

How can I do that?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: `{{ factsheet['name_' + language] }}`

Comment: just to note: use `i18n` for localization https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/i18n

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation

Comment: For i18n (internationalization) and l10n (localization) you can also try http://angular-translate.github.io/ - it is easier to handle and has more features (at least in my opinion) [And if someone is wondering what this i18n and l10n is all about: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeronym ;)]